# Many to one relationships in mongoose. How to access and output the referred to object ID's?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

I'm trying to create a "wishlist" feature for users on my node / mongo application. I've assumed the best way to model the scheme would be to reference the items they like. So far my reading has brought me to this point (I'm not very familiar with the Types.ObjectID):

**Schema Model**

```
var UserSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  email: {
    type: String,
    unique: true,
    required: true,
    trim: true
  },
  password: {
    type: String,
    required: true
  },
  wishlist: [{
    type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
    ref: "Wishlist",
    required: true
  }]
});
```

I've managed to write some code which pushes the relevant _id into the "Likes" array:

```
Product.findById(productID).exec(function (err, user) {
    User.updateOne({ _id: req.session.userId }, { "$push": { "wishlist": productID } }, function (err, user) {
      if (err) {
        console.log("Failed to add")
      } else {
        console.log(productID + " has been added")
      }
    });
 });
```

This outputs in the database like so:

```
{
        "_id" : ObjectId("5c3f7e1f1268203b1f31cb17"),
        "email" : "email",
        "password" : "password",
        "__v" : 0,
        "wishlist" : [
                ObjectId("5c41f4b42f82b14798d5c7fc"),
                ObjectId("5c41f4b42f82b14798d5c7ff")
        ]
}
```

I'm stuck on how I'd output these wishlist items in my template. My assumption was to get the data like this:

```
router.get('/wishlist', middleware.requiresLogin, function(req, res, next) {

  User.findOne({ _id: req.session.userId }, function(err, user) {
    res.render('wishlist', {
      title: 'Wishlist',
      template: 'wishlist',
      saved: user.wishlist,
      header: true,
      footer: true
    });
  });
});
```

And the loop through the items like this:

```
{{#each saved }} Code goes here {{/each }}
```

Am I approaching this correctly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you'll need to populate the wishlist field, try this,

```
User.findOne({ _id: req.session.userId }).
  populate('wishlist').
  exec(function (err, user) {
    res.render('wishlist', {
      title: 'Wishlist',
      template: 'wishlist',
      saved: user.wishlist,
      header: true,
      footer: true
    });
  });
```

Answer (score 0):

You can refer to the [**Populate**](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/populate.html) (mongoose documentation).

```
//User_controller.js
exports.getUser = (req, res) => {
    User.findOne({ _id: req.session.userId })
       .populate('wishlist')
       .then((user) => { res.json(user) })
       .catch((error) => { res.status(500).json({ error })
       });
   };

// UserRoute.js
        const express = require("express");
        const router = express.Router();

        const userCtrl = require('./user_controller');
        router.get('/:id', userCtrl.getUser);
        module.exports = router;



//server.js 
            //...
            const userRoute = require("./UserRoute");
            app.use("/user", userRoute);
            //...
```